# OpenCV get ApproxPolyDP corner points?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get the ApproxPolyDP corner points. I'm finding contours with `cv.findContours(edged, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` and putting them in loop, then I'm processing this in the loop:

```
peri = cv.arcLength(cnt, true);
cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, tmp, 0.02 * peri, true);
```

I can get `boundingRect` from contours but I want to get the four points of rotated and angled rectengular.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++: RotatedRect minAreaRect(InputArray points)

Python: cv.MinAreaRect2(points, storage=None) → Box2D

Use minAreaRect function  to get rotated  rectangle corners .

EDIT :

cv.MinAreaRect2 will return "Box2D" as ( center , (width,height) , angle)

and if you need rectangle corners use cv2.cv.BoxPoints().

Comment: It's not getting angle

Comment: I edit my answer. with cv.MinAreaRect2 you get the rotattion angle.